# VssHttpMessageHandler and HttpMessageHandler pooling

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-devops

I'm currently using Azure Devops Client librairies for C#.
For many reasons (such as avoiding port exhaustion or testability), I would like to use the IHttpMessageHandlerFactory provided by dotnetcore to provide handlers to my VssConnection.
Currently, I use this :

```
var vssHttpMessageHandler = new VssHttpMessageHandler(new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, options.Pat), VssClientHttpRequestSettings.Default.Clone(), _httpMessageHandlerFactory.CreateHandler(HttpClientName));
```

However, this does not always work as when the handler is reused, an exception is thrown :

> System.InvalidOperationException handled at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw:
> at System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.CheckDisposedOrStarted (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpMessageHandler.ApplySettings (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)

In fact, when constructing the VssHttpMessageHandler, new settings are applied to the HttpMessageHandler however, this one does not support being modified after its usage has started (all its properties call CheckDisposedOrStarted when set).

What can I do to achieve what I would like to do ?

Edit: here is a repro of my code

```
var azureDevopsUri = "https://dev.azure.com/mycollection";
var pat = "mypathere";

var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddHttpClient();
services.AddTransient(s =>
{
    var handlerFactory = s.GetRequiredService<IHttpMessageHandlerFactory>();    
    var vssHandler = new VssHttpMessageHandler(
        new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, pat),
        VssClientHttpRequestSettings.Default.Clone(),
        handlerFactory.CreateHandler());
    return new VssConnection(
                        new Uri(azureDevopsUri),
                        vssHandler,
                        new DelegatingHandler[] { });
});

var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

using(var scope = provider.CreateScope())
{
    var connection = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<VssConnection>();
    var client = await connection.GetClientAsync<ProjectCollectionHttpClient>();
    await client.GetProjectCollections();
}

using (var scope = provider.CreateScope())
{
    var connection = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<VssConnection>(); // <-- Exception thrown here
    var client = await connection.GetClientAsync<ProjectCollectionHttpClient>();
    await client.GetProjectCollections();
}
```

As you can see, when I configure a VssConnection not as a singleton (which is the workaround I found to be working right now), the second time I create an instance, I have the exception thrown as the IHttpMessageHandlerFactory used for pooling might have already been used.

Exception details :

```
This instance has already started one or more requests. Properties can only be modified before sending the first request. 
   at System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.CheckDisposedOrStarted()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.set_AllowAutoRedirect(Boolean value)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpMessageHandler.ApplySettings(HttpMessageHandler handler, ICredentials defaultCredentials, VssHttpRequestSettings settings)
   at UserQuery.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Main>b__0(IServiceProvider s), line 9
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at UserQuery.Main(), line 31
```

Comment: You could refer to the sample in the answer. Since I couldn't reproduce this issue based on your code, could you please share more sample code and the steps to reproduce this issue? On the other hand, you can directly assign arguments to vssconnection to connect.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/samples?view=azure-devops#authenticating

Comment: I've updated my message with a repro. Issue is when reusing a HttpMessageHandler provided by the pool.

Comment: Hi @Nathanael Marchand. Thanks for your information. I could reproduce this issue. Based on my test, if I remove the `handlerFactory.CreateHandler()`, it will build successfully. Could you please try it and check if it could make some changes.

Comment: Yes I know that I can let the sdk create the handler however it might lead to a socket exhaustion.
That's why I wanted to use the pooling improvements brought by aspnetcore/dotnetcore (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0 )

Answer (score 0):

I tested with the `VssHttpMessageHandler`, but I couldn't reproduce this issue.

I would like to share the C# sample:

```
 var azureDevopsUri = "https://dev.azure.com/org";
            var pat = "PAT";

            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            services.AddHttpClient();
            services.AddTransient(s =>
            {
                var handlerFactory = s.GetRequiredService<IHttpMessageHandlerFactory>();
                var vssHandler = new VssHttpMessageHandler(
                    new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, pat),
                    VssClientHttpRequestSettings.Default.Clone());
                return new VssConnection(
                                    new Uri(azureDevopsUri),
                                    vssHandler,
                                    new DelegatingHandler[] { });
            });

            var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            using (var scope = provider.CreateScope())
            {
                var connection = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<VssConnection>();
                var client = await connection.GetClientAsync<ProjectCollectionHttpClient>();
                await client.GetProjectCollections();
            }

            using (var scope = provider.CreateScope())
            {
                var connection = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<VssConnection>(); // <-- Exception thrown here
                var client = await connection.GetClientAsync<ProjectCollectionHttpClient>();
                await client.GetProjectCollections();
            }
```

**Note:** The Package:**Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client**:16.143.2.

In the package, the `VssHttpMessageHandler` definition:

```
public VssHttpMessageHandler(VssCredentials credentials, VssHttpRequestSettings settings, HttpMessageHandler innerHandler);
```